# Partially external linkage

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have the following problem to deal with:

- There is an external component compiled into a .lib file for static linkage
- The external component requires a specific function/operator interface to be available (i.e., the function must be present in another compilation unit)
- I do not want this function to be accessible by code that isn't in the external component
- I do not have any control of this specific function interface (or access to any portion of the external component source code), it's a given function in a global scope

Is there any way to achieve this?
If it matters, the compiler is `VC++ 2012`.

**Edit**:

- The output binary shall be single, so DLLs and similar won't do.
- Is it possible to limit symbol visibility to among .obj files in a single .lib but not to other .libs? If it's possible, I'd compile the function into a .lib and repackage it with the external .lib.

Comment: I'm really curious about the downvote, care to comment?

Comment: +1 to rebalance random downvote

Comment: Are you trying to make sure during your own link process that no other code using the function?  Or are you trying to prevent other users of the library containing the function from using the function (inadvertently or otherwise)?

Comment: @AnonMail In order to use the external library a specific function must be provided. This function functionality is very close to the functionality of other functions that I have but it's not good enough for my internal purposes (yet can be used easily), therefore I do not want to allow other developers to have access to this specific function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably can't be achieved directly. Static libs by definition do not undergo linkage but rather just supply building blocks for executable binaries, so there is no sense in wanting to expose a symbol to be consumed only by a static lib. Static libs just do not 'consume' symbols - only binaries (that undergo linkage) do.

But you may be able to vastly reduce the chances of someone using your custom library callback, if you build it into an obj file and re-package it along with the static lib.   [LIB can do that.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e17b885t.aspx)  No one else would have access to the source - or header - of your custom callback, but the implementation would still be exported from the lib if someone hacked it's exact symbol name (which I assme is what you're trying to defend from).

Comment: Thanks, that's the closest I thought of as well. Unfortunately, the exported function is an overload of a commonly used operator, so its signature isn't a secret and might be used naturally without hacking the exact symbol name

Comment: Then I'm afraid this can't be done. The external static lib insisted on making use of a global function at global scope and you don't control it's source, so (short of hacking it's binary object code) you simply cannot feed it anything else.

Comment: I'll accept this answer for the clear explanation why it can't be done (libs do not consume symbols - ergo, the consequences).

Answer (score 1):

Compile the static lib and an implementation of the interface it should use into a DLL.

Things to watch out for:

- dllexport info: This is attached to the object code, in order to export it from the DLL you might have to either mess with it directly or use dllexported wrapper functions.
- runtime: If the DLL and final program both link the runtime statically, transferring memory between the two is going to cause problems. If both use a DLL runtime, you should be fine. Of course, this also affects debug builds, which add another possible variant to the runtime.

Comment: I'd prefer not to do this due to the complications you mentioned in addition to others (the environment is Windows Kernel, so things get more complicated). For now, the output binary shall be single

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find any documentation on not exporting certain symbols using the Windows linker although I think this functionality seems to exists in the gnu linker.

One thing you may try is to have your new function/operator use and therefore depend on some other function, say MyFunction, in another .lib.  That .lib would only contain MyFunction and it's only purpose would be to supply this dependency so you can successfully link your binary.  Without this new .lib, anyone who uses your new function would not be able to successfully link.  Presumably, it would be easier to control this other .lib that your core library.

You would want MyFunction to essentially be a noop except for the fact that you don't want the optimizer to eliminate the call to it.  Also, you may be able to just have your function/operator use a data item (instead of making a function call) contained in this other .lib, again with the same optimizer caveat.

Comment: Not sure I understand the suggestion. Let's say I add this new .lib that you propose. My core module needs to be linked to the external module that requires the mentioned function. Now with the new dependency it will have to be linked to another .lib as well. And I end up with all 3 .libs linked, exposing the undesired function to my core module.

Comment: I presumed the external module and your core library were separate.  Your executable would require all three .libs.  Everyone else would just use the core library.  If they attempt to use your new function/operator contained in the core lib, it won't link.

Comment: There are only 2 distinct components that need to be linked together - mine (can consist of multiple libs) and the external one. I don't want the func to be accessible from my component, but it needs to be provided ssomehow